# How to simplify multiple awaits with a single 'await Task.WhenAll'?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I assume that I have to use `Task.WhenAll` in the code below but cannot figure out hot it should be implemented properly.

Please, help.

```
 public async void UpdateData()
        {
            var month = (cbMonths.SelectedItem as MonthView).ID;
            var year = (cbYears.SelectedItem as YearView).ID;
            var deviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType;
            var calendar = await GetCalendar(month, year, deviceTypeID);
            var workTypes = await GetWorkTypes(); 

            if (calendar != null && workTypes != null) // Task.WhenAll ???
            {
                //...
            }
        }


 private async Task<List<WorkTypeItem>> GetWorkTypes()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var url = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerBaseUrl + @"/api/staff/WorkTypes";

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)    // Check the response StatusCode
                {
                    var serSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };    
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MSOCommon.WorkTypeItem>>(responseBody, serSettings); 
                }              
                else
                {
                    logger.Error(Properties.Resources.DATACannotGetWorkTypes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(Properties.Resources.DATACannotGetWorkTypes + " " + ex.Message);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You want to make multiple calls to the HttpClient then await all of the GetAsync responses before leaving the method?

Comment: @Jasen I want to get all data from both datasources and only after this process data. So if some dataset is missing I have to generate error.

Comment: @Dimi I was looking at the wrong method. removed comment.

Comment: @Dimi dont await the methods. pass their tasks into a variables and call them in `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: @Nkosi Great! Please put your answer with code example.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm speaking naively, but why wouldn't the above code work? Since the method is `async`, and uses `await` on each of the asynchronous calls, the `if (calendar != null && workTypes != null)` will only execute after the previous two statements finish. Isn't it?

Comment: @crazyGamer You are right, bro! That was my initial guess. So you think that nothing wrong with code at all?

Comment: No, I don't think there is anything wrong. `Task.WhenAll` is an alternative when you have many calls to make. See this line from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await): "The await operator is applied to a task in an asynchronous method to insert a suspension point in the execution of the method until the awaited task completes."

Comment: Code will work either way. The difference is in the way they execute. in your OP each task will execute one after the other. with `Task.WhenAll`, they execute simultaneously.

Comment: @crazyGamer you are correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want both task to execute simultaneously, then don't `await` the methods. Instead pass their tasks into a variables and call them in `Task.WhenAll`

```
public async Task UpdateData() {
    var month = (cbMonths.SelectedItem as MonthView).ID;
    var year = (cbYears.SelectedItem as YearView).ID;
    var deviceTypeID = (int)DeviceType;
    var task1 = GetCalendar(month, year, deviceTypeID);
    var task2 = GetWorkTypes(); 

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

    var calendar = task1.Result;
    var workTypes = task2.Result;
}
```

Also note that you should avoid `async void` methods.

Comment: +1 for pointing out `async void`. It is better to return the `Task` object, as you have more control over the execution, when calling it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var calendarTask = GetCalendar(month, year, deviceTypeID);
var workTypesTask = GetWorkTypes(); 

Task.WaitAll(calendarTask, workTypesTask);
var calendar = await calendarTask;
var workTypes = await workTypesTask;
```

To answer @crazyGamer , the reason you do this is so that both tasks can run at the same time.  Otherwise you're waiting for the first task before you even start working on the 2nd.  Of course, if they depend on each other, that's a good thing.  Otherwise, this'll tend to run faster on MP systems.

Comment: You shouldn't await twice, which you effectively do with this code. WaitAll isn't needed in this case. Either that, or "ditch" the awaits, and replace with accessing `.Result` instead.

Comment: @JohnySkovdal - from msdn on `.Result`: "Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method" (it's certain arguable that at this point using `.Result` is more clear, but I don't love properties with side-effects, so avoid it as a general rule)

Comment: my point was simply, that you're already awaiting with Task.WaitAll and you might as well skip that line if you're using await again on the same tasks?